# C: Check if a two-dimensional array is on descending order excluding 0

Tags: c, arrays

I need to check if a two-dimensional array is in descending order.

I wrote a soultion but not satisfied with it.
Here is my working code:

```
bool sorted(void)
{
    int prev = board[0][0];
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < d; j++){
            if (board[i][j] < prev){
                return false;
            }
            prev = board[i][j];
            counter++;
            if (counter == d * d - 1 ){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I am looking for a way to use only conditionals, without a counter. Here is what I tried:

```
bool sorted(void)
{
    int prev = board[0][0];
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < d; j++){
            if (board[i][j] < prev && board[i][j] != 0){
                return false;
            }
            prev = board[i][j];
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This doesn't work. Assuming the array is sorted, without

```
 && board[i][j] != 0
```

as soon as the last element is checked, I get false, because 0 < 1.

I almost wrecked my head.
Could you give some ideas, please? Thanks!

Comment: this doesn't look like javascript.

Comment: Sorry guys. I worked with JS a lot, and put it here accidentally :D This is C.

Comment: Put together [minimal, **complete**, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem. [Something like this](http://ideone.com/bJdCWe), but actually does what you claim, and use *that* example as your question code.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
bool sorted(void)
{
    int prev = board[0][0];
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < d; j++){
            if (board[i][j] < prev && board[i][j] != 0){
                return false;
            }
        }
       prev = board[i][j];
    }
return true;
}
```

Comment: This won't compile, as `j` is no longer in scope when `prev = board[i][j];` is encountered. Further, moving the `j` decl out of the for-loop initializer won't solve the problem either, as it ensures an out-of-range violation upon `j == d` (the condition that broken the inner for-loop).

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem changing the initial value of `prev`:

```
#include <limits.h>                   // for INT_MIN

// ...

bool sorted(void)
{
    int prev = INT_MIN;               // <-- initialize with the lowest possible value
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < d; j++){
            if (board[i][j] < prev){
                return false;
            }
            prev = board[i][j];
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```